# Hibernate bidirectional query

Tags: performance, hibernate

I have a question regarding Hibernate bidirectional. Lets say I have 2 classes, `Class A` and `Class B` and bidirectionally related. That means when I query `Class A`, I also can get `Class B` and vice versa. My question is how hibernate work when I do this

```
ClassA classA = ClassA.findClassAById(1);
ClassB = classA.getClassB().getClassA().getClassB();
```

I know I can get `ClassB` with just `classA.getClassB();`, but I also can get `classA.getClassB().getClassA().getClassB().getClassA().getClassB()...;`

Can someone explain to me how hibernate work with bidirectional query?

I'm concerned about performance.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate employes an efficient first level cache also known as the [PersistantContext](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/engine/PersistenceContext.html)
If an object is loaded in the context , hibernate does not hit the database to get the same object.

In the problem statement when `findClassAById(1)` is called `classA` object is loaded in the persistance context. `classB` object is loaded at the same time or later depending on the lazy loading/eager loading strategy adopted. Following which the database should not be hit ideally for all future calls.

You can very well google Persistance Context for more information about how it works.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Can you may be help me understand, how you can write unit tests for such entities which has bidirectional mapping. For ex I want to write unit test for class A then I will have to mock classA.setClassB(instance of classB) and  classB.setClassA(instance of classA), hibernate can manage the entities but when it comes to unit tests, this will throw StackOverflow error. And to be honest it should throw because here there is no hibernate entity-manager to manage the entities, here we are mocking the objects. Is there something wrong with my assumption ?